# Why are all my live Stripe payment attempts failing?

Tags: civicontribute, stripe

CiviCRM 5.49.1 with Drupal 7. I have three contribution pages (a donation, a membership and an event registration). All three use the Stripe payment processor (latest version = 6.7.3), and have been working well. However we've seen lots of payments not being successful in recent weeks so I'm trying to understand what's going wrong. Test drive payments on all three pages work fine. Live payments all fail.
Can't see any obvious clues in the CiviCRM log file. All that's there is lots of entries like this:

```
May 19 09:02:29  [error] Stripe.process_stripe: Unable to cancel paymentIntent. The resource ID cannot be null or whitespace.
```

Looking at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/stripe/-/issues/365 which relates to this error message it doesn't appear to be critical,  but I'll delete the rows that down't have street_intent_id - looks like there are just a couple.

Any clues as to how to get my live payments working again greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got the bottom of this, once I was granted access to the Stripe account. The account was configured to use a 2016 version of the Stripe API. Updating that to the version recommended by the Stripe extension, and everything started working.I guess my test transactions were working because I wasn't using test card numbers that triggered the 3DSecure validation.

what I'm sort of surprised by is why Stripe itself was allowing an account to use a 2016 version of the API, which presumably was built before 3DSecure was even a thing. And when my client raised a query with Stripe as to why the transaction were all failing, they didn't flag up the API version as a possible candidate.